# One page scrooler jquery not working correctly in IE8 browser

Tags: jquery

I used one page scroling jquery in my website. When i click about button the page some scrool down started the page. This problem only in IE8 browser Pls suggest the reason.

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.navOne').onePageNav({
  begin: function() {
  console.log('start');
  },
  end: function() {
  console.log('stop');
  },
 scrollOffset: 120
 });
});

Answer (score 1):

I doubt whether IE8 supports jquery one  page Scroller .Try using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: Yeah. fullpage.js does.